# I am not able to connect to database when i was using appdomain?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

I am not able to connect to database context. If using assembly i can connect but using appdomain only getting problem .

I am getting below error:

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: Your connection string information might be wrong. Check your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is neither an appdomain issue nor a connection string issue. Please check **This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently.**